# MongoDB: aggregation with update field by condition

Tags: mongodb

Please tell me how can i update field with condition in aggregate?

```
[{_id:"1",val:"admin",...},{_id:"2",val:'employee',...},{_id:"3",val:"admin",...},...]
```

New data: "admin-en","employee-en"

```
Collection.aggregate([{
  $project: {
   $cond: {
 if: {$eq:"admin"},
then: {$set:"admin-en"},
if: {$eq:"employee"},
then: {$set: "employee-en"}
}
 }
}])
```

I'm most likely doing something wrong. Maybe there is some other way to update a field with a condition using aggregation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update in an `aggregate` query but you can use aggregate stages into a `update` query. Check [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

By the way I'm not sure if I've understood correctly but maybe you only need this query:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "val": {
        "$concat": [
          "$val",
          "-en"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A24qGbx25jz).

But, if you want to use `if/else` statement you can try with [$switch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) (which i.e. is an `if/else` structure):

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "val": {
        "$switch": {
          "branches": [
            {
              "case": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$val",
                  "admin"
                ]
              },
              "then": "admin-en"
            },
            {
              "case": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$val",
                  "employee"
                ]
              },
              "then": "employee-en"
            }
          ],
          "default": "$val"
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iCQHgPFZMGt).

Also only using `if/else` example is [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pGFX5UzFkBb).

Note that:

- First example will update all `$val`.
- Second and third examples will update only `$val` with value "admin" or "employee".

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but i need to do it with aggregation and was hoping it could be done in aggregation